# How does Browscap work?

Tags: 7, theming, mobile-tools

How does Browscap work? Every Browser seems to be a crawler. I think that is a bug. How can I fix that?

I'll used this [tutorial](http://compuccino.com/labs/blog/2010/03/01/howto-mobile-leistungsoptimierte-website-mit-drupal) and get this execption on the mobile url:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'false' for column 'is_crawler' at row 1: UPDATE {browscap_statistics} SET counter=counter + 1, is_crawler=:db_update_placeholder_0 WHERE ( (parent = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ); Array ( [:db_update_placeholder_0] => false [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => Firefox 10.0 ) in browscap_exit() (Zeile 134 von x:\somewhere\sites\all\modules\browscap\browscap.module).

---

In replay to paul-m here are my settings:

Current browscap data version: 4911.
Enable automatic updates is enabled.
Enable user agent log is also enabled.

If I refresh the Browscap data I'll get everytime a timeout after 30 seconds. Also If run the cronjob it timesout after 240 seconds. Not sure what I do wrong.

`/admin/reports/browscap/browsers` shows me an empty list, but `/admin/reports/browscap/crawlers` containes all browsers.

Comment: This is a bug in the module, which you should report issue queue. It's that there already is a bug report and maybe even a patch for this.

Comment: I'm new with drupal, so that I don't know where to write that.

Comment: See http://drupal.org/project/issues/browscap. However, when looking at the current code, it doesn't look like it should produce the error you're seeing. Make sure you're using the most recent version before reporting this.

Comment: I rerun the update script multible times. No success.

Comment: @rekire What you are reporting is caused by a bug in the module. Those questions are not on-topic, here. If you notice a bug on a module, you should report that on the project issue queue, as Berdir said. Questions like this don't help any future reader, and the project maintainer doesn't fix the module just because you ask here a question about a bug in the module.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Thank you for your answer. Now I understand that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I vaguely recall having that same error message, and running update.php solved it. So make sure you've installed the latest version and run update.php.

To get Browscap to log non-crawler user agents, head to `/admin/reports/browscap/browsers` and follow the instructions. They tell you to enable 'Monitor browsers' on the Browscap configuration screen.

To participate in the issue queue of Browscap, or any Drupal project, go to [the project page](http://drupal.org/project/browscap) and look on the right side. You'll see a list of maintainers, and under that a section called Issues for Browscap. Search for your issue there. Or just go to the project's [issue list](http://drupal.org/project/issues/browscap?categories=All).

Comment: In replay to your answer I updated my question.

Comment: Just wondering - Did you flush the cache?

Comment: I'll altered an file to fix that "bug". I found somewhere on drupal.org a patch file which I used to create an own patch. I added in `browscap.module` an inline if statement --> `$user_agent_crawler = check_plain(trim($user_agent['crawler'])) ? 1 : 0;`. Now is the error message gone. @StanAscher I flushed the cache also with no success all browsers are crawlers...

Comment: @rekire If that *somewhere* is an issue in the module, then respond there that the patch works and set it to RTBC (reviewed and tested by the community). If it's e.g. in the forum, create an issue and post your patch and set it to needs review. This way, the maintainer is made aware of the problem and can fix it, so that you don't need to re-apply your patch the next time you update the module.